# How to use ES6 modules instead of namespaces in the global scope?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

When defining a class in ES6, it becomes available in the global scope, which you can prevent with the new ES6 bracket enclosure:

```
{
  class Car {
    constructor(make) { 
        this.make = make;
        this.currentSpeed = 25;
    }

    getSpeed(){
          console.log(this.make + ' is going ' + this.currentSpeed + ' mph.');
    }
  }
  window.MYNAMESPACE.Car = Car;
}
```

I have multiple js files, each with their own class definition, and I make the classes available via MYNAMESPACE in the global scope. 
So creating a new car from anywhere looks like:

```
var myCar = new MYNAMESPACE.Car();
```

How could I use ES6 modules for this? Is that even possible, or recommendable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using ES6 exports and imports instead of making the classes available in global scope.

```
// car.js
class Car {
  constructor(make) { 
        this.make = make;
        this.currentSpeed = 25;
  }

  getSpeed(){
    console.log(this.make + ' is going ' + this.currentSpeed + ' mph.');
  }
}

export default Car;

// foo.js    
import Car from "./car"

var car = new Car("ford");
car.getSpeed();
```

Read up on es6 module syntax from

1. http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html
2. MDN:

   - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class
   - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
   - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: Thanks! A simple example can go a long way! Those links tend to overload the poor reader with the world's most elaborate examples :)

Comment: By the way, can I leave out the {  } anonymous brackets at the start/end of each class? What is the best way to init a main app.js after window.onload?

Comment: @Kokodo you can leave them out. For the initing you can just include a js file with <script>-tags, in which you import the App itself from "./app.js" and call the init after window.onload (or just bake it into app.js) like you normally would do.

Comment: OK, and then I need to convert ES6 > ES5 and use something like Browserify to get the 'require' keyword working in current browsers, right? (just trying to get my workflow in order :)

Comment: Yup. Look into Babelify, it does the conversion during the browserify process.

Comment: Thx :) I got it all working! Confusion was caused by all the different workflows: babelify, babel, npm build scripts, grunt/gulp,browserify, webpack, etc, etc, etc, etc.... I'm still pondering the optimal approach.

Comment: @Kokodoko great! Don't worry about the optimal approach too much, find one that fits you: if you ran into a wall with the tools you use and want to switch, you can always do what later :)